# Error #1452: Cannot add or update a child row - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

me sale este error al momento de importar una base en MYSQL

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cotejamiento de la misma es utf8_unicode_ci, esta es la base

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.1.1
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Servidor: 127.0.0.1
-- Tiempo de generación: 17-05-2022 a las 16:42:40
-- Versión del servidor: 10.4.22-MariaDB
-- Versión de PHP: 8.1.2

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `sistema_encuestasv1`
--

DELIMITER $$
--
-- Procedimientos
--
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SPresultado_grafica` (IN `id_pregunta` INT(11))  BEGIN
SET @suma = (SELECT 
        sum(usuarios.porcentaje_participacion) 
        FROM opciones 
        INNER JOIN preguntas ON opciones.id_pregunta=preguntas.id_pregunta 
        INNER JOIN resultados ON opciones.id_opcion=resultados.id_opcion 
        INNER JOIN usuarios ON resultados.id_usuario=usuarios.id_usuario
        INNER JOIN encuestas ON resultados.id_encuesta=encuestas.id_encuesta
        WHERE preguntas.id_pregunta = id_pregunta);
        
/* ESTE ES EL QUE FUNCIONA */
SELECT 
        preguntas.id_pregunta, 
        encuestas.titulo,
        opciones.valor,
        resultados.id_usuario,
        usuarios.porcentaje_participacion,
        sum(usuarios.porcentaje_participacion) suma2,
        @suma,
        TRUNCATE((sum(usuarios.porcentaje_participacion)*100)/ @suma,2) as count
        FROM opciones 
        INNER JOIN preguntas ON opciones.id_pregunta=preguntas.id_pregunta 
        INNER JOIN resultados ON opciones.id_opcion=resultados.id_opcion 
        INNER JOIN usuarios ON resultados.id_usuario=usuarios.id_usuario
        INNER JOIN encuestas ON resultados.id_encuesta=encuestas.id_encuesta
        WHERE preguntas.id_pregunta = id_pregunta
        group by opciones.valor
        ORDER BY opciones.valor;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `encuestas`
--

CREATE TABLE `encuestas` (
  `id_encuesta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `titulo` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `estado` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_inicio` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `fecha_final` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `encuestas`
--

INSERT INTO `encuestas` (`id_encuesta`, `id_usuario`, `titulo`, `descripcion`, `estado`, `fecha_inicio`, `fecha_final`) VALUES
(3, 0, '¿Se da por recibido el informe del Gerente General sobre el ejercicio financiero de la sociedad al año 2020?', '', 1, '2022-03-15 15:17:50', '2022-03-15 16:21:50');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `opciones`
--

CREATE TABLE `opciones` (
  `id_opcion` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_pregunta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `valor` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `opciones`
--

INSERT INTO `opciones` (`id_opcion`, `id_pregunta`, `valor`) VALUES
(7, 3, 'A favor'),
(8, 3, 'En contra'),
(9, 3, 'Abstenerse');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `preguntas`
--

CREATE TABLE `preguntas` (
  `id_pregunta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_encuesta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `titulo` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `id_tipo_pregunta` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `preguntas`
--

INSERT INTO `preguntas` (`id_pregunta`, `id_encuesta`, `titulo`, `id_tipo_pregunta`) VALUES
(3, 3, 'Seleccione', 1);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `resultados`
--

CREATE TABLE `resultados` (
  `id_resultado` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_opcion` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_encuesta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `resultados`
--

INSERT INTO `resultados` (`id_resultado`, `id_opcion`, `id_encuesta`, `id_usuario`) VALUES
(1, 7, 3, 'agodoy'),
(2, 9, 3, 'br2022'),
(3, 7, 3, 'ihss2022'),
(4, 7, 3, 'inju2022'),
(5, 7, 3, 'impre2022'),
(6, 7, 3, 'sefi2022'),
(7, 7, 3, 'ipm2022'),
(8, 7, 3, 'promo'),
(9, 7, 3, 'lalfaro'),
(10, 7, 3, 'bicafe'),
(11, 7, 3, 'rbarrios'),
(12, 7, 3, 'cglobal'),
(13, 7, 3, 'chic'),
(14, 7, 3, 'fcn'),
(15, 7, 3, 'ihcafe'),
(16, 7, 3, 'ahpro'),
(17, 7, 3, 'ar2022'),
(18, 8, 3, 'adm'),
(19, 7, 3, 'vgarcia');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `tipo_pregunta`
--

CREATE TABLE `tipo_pregunta` (
  `id_tipo_pregunta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` text COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `tipo_pregunta`
--

INSERT INTO `tipo_pregunta` (`id_tipo_pregunta`, `nombre`, `descripcion`) VALUES
(1, 'Selección múltiple', 'Se podrá escoger solo una opción\r\nelemento input type radio');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `tipo_usuario`
--

CREATE TABLE `tipo_usuario` (
  `id_tipo_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `tipo_usuario`
--

INSERT INTO `tipo_usuario` (`id_tipo_usuario`, `nombre`) VALUES
(1, 'Administrador'),
(2, 'Usuario'),
(3, 'Usuario_Vista');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `usuarios`
--

CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `clave` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `nombres` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `id_tipo_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `porcentaje_participacion` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `usuarios`
--

INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`id`, `id_usuario`, `clave`, `nombres`, `apellidos`, `email`, `id_tipo_usuario`, `porcentaje_participacion`) VALUES
(1, 'prueba1', '123', 'Prueba1', 'P1', 'prueba@correo.com', 2, '0.00'),
(2, 'admin', 'Admin@2022', 'Administrador', 'AD', 'admin@correo.com', 1, '0.00'),
(3, 'agodoy', 'tempo1', 'Alfredo Chinchilla', 'bicafe', 'admin@correo.com', 2, '0.15'),
(4, 'ahpro', 'tempo2', 'Asociacion Hondureña Cafe', 'bicafe', 'admin@correo.com', 2, '0.03'),
(5, 'alopez', 'tempo3', 'Bicafe Honduras', 'bicafe', 'admin@correo.com', 2, '0.01'),
(6, 'ana2022', 'tempo4', 'Bicafe Honduras', 'bicafe', 'admin@correo.com', 2, '0.00'),
(7, 'apontaza', 'tempo5', 'Alejandro Pontaza', 'bicafe', 'admin@correo.com', 2, '0.08'),
(8, 'ar2022', 'tempo6', 'Bicafe Honduras', 'bicafe', 'admin@correo.com', 2, '0.00'),
(9, 'basi', 'tempo7', 'Basilio Hawit', 'bicafe', 'admin@correo.com', 2, '0.04'),
(10, 'bicafe', 'tempo8', 'Bicafe Honduras', 'bicafe', 'admin@correo.com', 2, '0.39'),
(11, 'br2022', 'tempo9', 'Banco de Desarrollo Rural', 'Banrural', 'banrural@correo.com', 2, '72.45'),
(12, 'carlos2022', 'tempo10', 'Carlos Alfredo', 'Soto', 'carlos@correo.com', 2, '1.12'),
(13, 'ccafe', 'tempo11', 'Compañia de Cafe', 'bicafe', 'admin@correo.com', 2, '0.08'),
(14, 'cglobal', 'tempo12', 'Corporacion Global', 'bicafe', 'admin@correo.com', 2, '0.08'),
(15, 'chic', 'tempo13', 'Camara Industria Construccion', 'bicafe', 'admin@correo.com', 2, '0.07'),
(16, 'coinsu', 'tempo14', 'Corporacion Industrial Sula', 'bicafe', 'admin@correo.com', 2, '0.02'),
(17, 'earias', 'tempo15', 'Elsa Marina', 'bicafe', 'admin@correo.com', 2, '0.10'),
(18, 'ehernandez', 'tempo16', 'Evelio Hernandez', 'bicafe', 'admin@correo.com', 2, '0.02'),
(19, 'fcn', 'tempo17', 'Fondo Cafetalero Nacional', 'bicafe', 'admin@correo.com', 2, '0.06'),
(20, 'hawit', 'tempo18', 'Rommel Hawit', 'bicafe', 'admin@correo.com', 2, '0.04'),
(21, 'hemlet', 'tempo19', 'Terence Hawit', 'bicafe', 'admin@correo.com', 2, '0.04'),
(22, 'ihcafe', 'tempo20', 'IHCAFE', 'bicafe', 'admin@correo.com', 2, '0.06'),
(23, 'ihss2022', 'tempo21', 'Instituto Hondureño de Seguridad Social', 'IHSS', 'ihss@correo.com', 2, '7.04'),
(24, 'impre2022', 'tempo22', 'Instituto Nacional de Prevision del Magisterio', 'Inprema', 'inprema@correo.com', 2, '5.28'),
(25, 'inju2022', 'tempo23', 'Instituto Nacional de Jubilaciones', 'Injupemp', 'injupemp@correo.com', 2, '7.04'),
(26, 'ipm2022', 'tempo24', 'Instituto Hondureño Prevension Militar', 'IPM', 'ipm@correo.com', 2, '1.14'),
(27, 'jlopez', 'tempo25', 'Jorge Humberto', 'Lopez', 'admin@correo.com', 2, '0.46'),
(28, 'lalfaro', 'tempo26', 'Luis Alfaro', 'Gramajo', 'admin@correo.com', 2, '0.46'),
(29, 'mgomez', 'tempo27', 'Mario Roberto', 'bicafe', 'admin@correo.com', 2, '0.04'),
(30, 'msiguenza', 'tempo28', 'Miguel Siguenza', 'bicafe', 'admin@correo.com', 2, '0.15'),
(31, 'promo', 'tempo29', 'Promociones Bursatiles', 'Probursa', 'Probursa@correo.com', 2, '0.76'),
(32, 'rbarrios', 'tempo30', 'Ryan Barrios', 'bicafe', 'admin@correo.com', 2, '0.11'),
(33, 'sefi2022', 'tempo31', 'Servicios Financieros Regionales', 'SEFI', 'sefi@correo.com', 2, '1.52'),
(34, 'tgarcia', 'tempo32', 'Tulio Rene', 'Garcia', 'admin@correo.com', 2, '0.70'),
(35, 'vgarcia', 'tempo33', 'Victor Hugo', 'Garcia', 'admin@correo.com', 2, '0.46'),
(36, 'prueba2', '123', 'Prueba2', 'P2', 'prueba@correo.com', 2, '0.00')
(37, 'prueba3', '123', 'Prueba3', 'P3', 'prueba@correo.com', 2, '0.00');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `usuarios_encuestas`
--

CREATE TABLE `usuarios_encuestas` (
  `id_usuario` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `id_encuesta` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `usuarios_encuestas`
--

INSERT INTO `usuarios_encuestas` (`id_usuario`, `id_encuesta`) VALUES
('agodoy', 3),
('br2022', 3),
('ihss2022', 3),
('inju2022', 3),
('impre2022', 3),
('sefi2022', 3),
('ipm2022', 3),
('promo', 3),
('lalfaro', 3),
('bicafe', 3),
('rbarrios', 3),
('cglobal', 3),
('chic', 3),
('fcn', 3),
('ihcafe', 3),
('ahpro', 3),
('ar2022', 3),
('adm', 3),
('vgarcia', 3);

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `encuestas`
--
ALTER TABLE `encuestas`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_encuesta`),
  ADD KEY `id_usuario` (`id_usuario`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `opciones`
--
ALTER TABLE `opciones`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_opcion`),
  ADD KEY `id_pregunta` (`id_pregunta`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `preguntas`
--
ALTER TABLE `preguntas`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_pregunta`),
  ADD KEY `id_encuesta` (`id_encuesta`),
  ADD KEY `id_tipo_pregunta` (`id_tipo_pregunta`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `resultados`
--
ALTER TABLE `resultados`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_resultado`),
  ADD KEY `id_opcion` (`id_opcion`),
  ADD KEY `id_encuesta` (`id_encuesta`),
  ADD KEY `id_usuario` (`id_usuario`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `tipo_pregunta`
--
ALTER TABLE `tipo_pregunta`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_tipo_pregunta`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `tipo_usuario`
--
ALTER TABLE `tipo_usuario`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_tipo_usuario`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `usuarios`
--
ALTER TABLE `usuarios`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_usuario`),
  ADD KEY `id_tipo_usuario` (`id_tipo_usuario`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `usuarios_encuestas`
--
ALTER TABLE `usuarios_encuestas`
  ADD KEY `id_usuario` (`id_usuario`),
  ADD KEY `id_encuesta` (`id_encuesta`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `encuestas`
--
ALTER TABLE `encuestas`
  MODIFY `id_encuesta` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `opciones`
--
ALTER TABLE `opciones`
  MODIFY `id_opcion` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=10;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `preguntas`
--
ALTER TABLE `preguntas`
  MODIFY `id_pregunta` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `resultados`
--
ALTER TABLE `resultados`
  MODIFY `id_resultado` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=20;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `tipo_pregunta`
--
ALTER TABLE `tipo_pregunta`
  MODIFY `id_tipo_pregunta` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `tipo_usuario`
--
ALTER TABLE `tipo_usuario`
  MODIFY `id_tipo_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;

--
-- Restricciones para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `opciones`
--
ALTER TABLE `opciones`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `opciones_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_pregunta`) REFERENCES `preguntas` (`id_pregunta`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `preguntas`
--
ALTER TABLE `preguntas`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `preguntas_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_tipo_pregunta`) REFERENCES `tipo_pregunta` (`id_tipo_pregunta`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `preguntas_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_encuesta`) REFERENCES `encuestas` (`id_encuesta`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `resultados`
--
ALTER TABLE `resultados`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `resultados_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_opcion`) REFERENCES `opciones` (`id_opcion`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `resultados_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_encuesta`) REFERENCES `encuestas` (`id_encuesta`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `resultados_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_usuario`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`id_usuario`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `usuarios`
--
ALTER TABLE `usuarios`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `usuarios_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_tipo_usuario`) REFERENCES `tipo_usuario` (`id_tipo_usuario`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `usuarios_encuestas`
--
ALTER TABLE `usuarios_encuestas`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `usuarios_encuestas_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_usuario`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`id_usuario`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `usuarios_encuestas_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_encuesta`) REFERENCES `encuestas` (`id_encuesta`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Saben que podrá generar el error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema esta aqui:

```
INSERT INTO `resultados` (`id_resultado`, `id_opcion`, `id_encuesta`, `id_usuario`) VALUES
(1, 7, 3, 'agodoy'),
(2, 9, 3, 'br2022'),
(3, 7, 3, 'ihss2022'),
(4, 7, 3, 'inju2022'),
(5, 7, 3, 'impre2022'),
(6, 7, 3, 'sefi2022'),
(7, 7, 3, 'ipm2022'),
(8, 7, 3, 'promo'),
(9, 7, 3, 'lalfaro'),
(10, 7, 3, 'bicafe'),
(11, 7, 3, 'rbarrios'),
(12, 7, 3, 'cglobal'),
(13, 7, 3, 'chic'),
(14, 7, 3, 'fcn'),
(15, 7, 3, 'ihcafe'),
(16, 7, 3, 'ahpro'),
(17, 7, 3, 'ar2022'),
(18, 8, 3, 'adm'),
(19, 7, 3, 'vgarcia');
```

Estas tratando de insertar el usuario `adm` pero eso usuario no existe.